# XNA get a sprite's top-left coordinate

Tags: c#, xna, location, coordinates, bounds

I'm having a trouble in getting a sprite's top-left coordinates. I tried to use texture2d.bounds with both bounds.location.x\y or bounds.left\top... But for some reason these parameters are x=0, y=0 and the object's movement wouldn't change it (even if the starting point is not 0,0).
how can I solve this?

Comment: A sprite that is already drawn? Not going to happen. Why isn't your sprite represented with an object with a position (that then draws the sprite at that position) so you already know where it is?

Answer (score 3):

`Texture2D.Bounds` gets the size of the resource, as seen on the [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.bounds.aspx). The `X` and `Y` positions will always be 0, and you should never need them, the only reason for `Bounds` is to get the `Width` and `Height` of the texture.

With that said, `Texture2D`'s only represent a texture, they do **not** represent a position. What you need to do is use a `Vector2`, a two-dimensional vector, to position your sprite.

**Example:**

```
Texture2D sprite;
Vector2 position;
...
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, position, Color.White)
    spriteBatch.End();
}
```

*Instead* of creating a position and texture for each sprite, you can make a separate sprite class to handle you position, texture, and drawing.

```
public class Sprite
{
    public Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }

    public Sprite(Texture2D texture, Vector2 initialPosition)
    {
         Texture = texture;
         Position = initialPosition;
    }
    public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Position, Color.White);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you mentioned what `Position` refers to, e.g. center, top-left, ... of the sprite

Comment: @dumbledad Position refers to whatever XNA uses by default, as you can see the position is just passed to spriteBatch.draw